# How To Set JSlider Selected Value To Global Variable?

Tags: java, swing, global-variables, return, jslider

Does anyone know how I would be able to send the selected value in the event handler for JSlider, `stateChanged` and set it to a global variable?

For example

```
public class Slider extends JPanel {

    public JSlider slider;
    public UserFrame frame;
    public double[] priceRange;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        new Slider();
    }

    public Slider() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        slider = new JSlider();
        priceRange = new double[2];

        slider.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Maximum Price in SEK"));

    /*
     * The minimum and maximum values are queried from the database. Those
     * values are then rounded up (maximum) to the nearest 10 SEK.
     * For example, if the minimum is 67 SEK and the maximum 95 SEK, then
     * the displayed range is [70, 100].
     */
        int min = (getMinimumPrice() / 10) * 10 + 10;
        int max = (getMaximumPrice() / 10) * 10 + 10;

        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        slider.setMinimum(min);
        slider.setMaximum(max);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        add(slider);
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
        if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            slider.getModel().setValue(slider.getModel().getValue());
            priceRange[0] = slider.getModel().getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

... and so on, ignore the methods `getMinimum` and `getMaximum` they simply retrieve the highest and lowest values in my database, but lets say all I want to happen when a user has released the JSlider knob is to set that to the `priceRange[0]`. How would I be able to that? I have tried creating a model and set that each time with the stateChanged I have also outside in an actionListener in my main set of code assigning something like so...

```
priceRange[0] = slider.getModel().getValue();
```

and then printing out that result and getting the minimum I set it too.

I really appreciate any further advice.

Have a great upcoming Holiday! :)

All The Best,
Marcus

Answer (score 2):

Just delete these lines:

```
slider.getModel().setValue(slider.getModel().getValue());
priceRange[0] = slider.getModel().getValue();
```

and insert this one instead:

```
priceRange[0] = (double)slider.getValue();
```

Good luck!

P.S. Where did you implement your `ChangeListener` interface at all?